# text in controller is never logged/never ran Angular Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm building an application in Rails and I'm using Angular for part of the front end, generating views based on data provided in a json file. I've been following [this](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/) tutorial, but I can't seem to get my controller to run and I have no idea why. Can anyone help me out?

Sample link: http://localhost:3000/events/events1

events.coffee.erb

```
app = angular.module('EventsApp', ['ui.router', 'templates'])

app.config [
  '$stateProvider'
  '$urlRouterProvider'
  ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state 'events',
      url: '/events/{id}'
      templateUrl: 'templates/_event.html'
      controller: 'EventsCtrl'
]

app.controller 'EventsCtrl', [
    '$scope'
    '$stateParams'
    ($scope, $stateParams) ->
        console.log $stateParams //this never shows up
        console.log 'Sup' //this never shows up
        $scope.greeting = 'Yo' //neither does this
]
```

events.html.erb

```
<div ng-app="EventsApp">
    Yo! //this shows up, but not {{greeting}}
    {{greeting}}
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

_event.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/event.html">
    <div>
        {{greeting}}
        Yo!
    </div>
</script>
```

Rails routes file:

```
get "events/*path" => "events#events"
```

Rails events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
    layout "application"

    def events
    end
end
```

File layout:

```
--app
-----assets
-------javascripts
----------templates
------------_event.html
----------events.coffee.erb
------views
--------events
----------events.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular code is poorly structured.  I think you are mixing up your Javascript syntax with your Ruby syntax...

Try something closer to this:

```
angular.module('EventsApp', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('events', {
        url = '/events/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'templates/_event.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  ])
  .controller('EventsCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$stateParams'
    function($scope, $stateParams) {
      console.log($stateParams); 
      console.log('Sup')
      $scope.greeting = 'Yo';
    }
  ]);
```